# Sleekxmpp: Working with more than one custom stanza

Tags: python, xmpp

I am working on creating a test for a xmpp client and I have the need to work with different custom stanzas along the way. I have two issues that I was wondering if you guys can help me:

1. As I mentioned, I will be using several stanzas with the same name but different namespace. Also this stanzas can be two level or more, here is an example:

STANZA 1

```
<iq type='result' to= 'chat.com'  id='id1'>
       <aa xmlns='http://mysite.com/profile' >
          <name>My name as included in sent mails<name>
          <lang>en</lang>
          <mail>My mail as included in sent mails</mail>
          <fbuserid>46736473231<fbuserid>
          <fbaccesstoken>AAAAA84257YTRRIXTEQITXXTCMTVBTTBXU<fbaccesstoken>
          <photo_url>http://pic.facebook.com/photo.jpg</photo_url>
      </aa>
</iq>
```

And I create the custom stanza as follow:

```
name = 'aa'
namespace = 'http://mysite.com/profile'
plugin_attrib = 'aa'
interfaces = set(('name', 'lang', 'mail', 'fbuserid', 'fbaccesstoken', 'photo_url'))
sub_interfaces = interfaces
```

STANZA 2

```
<iq type='set' to= 'roomname@conference.chat.come'  id='id1'>
 <aa xmlns='http://mysite.com/muc#share'>
   <item name='Falda tubo' thumbnail='http://webpage.info/falda_tn.jpg' id='itemid1' action='add' url='http://webpage.info/falda.html’>
      <metadata  path=' ' />
   </item>
 </aa>
</iq>
```

Question 1: How can I create stanzas of more than two levels?

1. As your can see, my stanzas have the same name but changes the namespace, this is giving me some trouble since I have created methods such as get_* and set_* to handle the info but it is being performed as:

   ```
   register_stanza_plugin(Iq, stanza_profile)
   register_stanza_plugin(Iq, stanza_rooms)

   def start(self, event):
       self.send_presence()
       self.get_parameters()
       self.set_parameters()
   ```

This register both stanzas but performs the actions only in the last one (stanza_rooms)

Question 2: How can I handle separately?

Working on python. Any help appreciated!

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

For your question about multiple stanzas with the same name, it is the `plugin_attrib` value that is important since that is what will distinguish between your two stanzas. Right now it looks like you've used `'aa'` for both stanza's `plugin_attrib` which leads to a conflict and the last registered stanza wins.

Typically, we use part of the namespace in these situations. For example, with disco there are two `query` elements with the namespaces `http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info` and `http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items`. So the two stanzas have the same `name`, different `namespace` values, and have `plugin_attrib` values of `'disco_info'` and `'disco_items'`, respectively.

It looks like you could use the names `aa_profile` and `aa_muc_share` or similar to resolve the issue.

For your other question, it looks like what you want are more stanza objects. One which provides the outer level container stanza, and the other which manages an individual subitem. You can make this work using:

```
class InnerStanza(ElementBase):
    name = 'inner'
    namespace = 'example'
    plugin_attrib = 'inner'
    plugin_multi_attrib = 'inner_items'
    ...

register_stanza_plugin(OuterStanza, InnerStanza, iterable=True)
```

With the above, you can access `outer['inner_items']` to get a list of the inner substanzas that match the InnerStanza class (because of the `plugin_multi_attrib` value).

-- Lance

Comment: Hello Lance, 
First, thanks for all the help you have given.  As you can see I have joined the sleekxmpp conference room but it seems we are in different time zones so it is hard to communicate.  With the help you have provided and some of the examples that you and Nathanial have created (https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP/wiki/Stanza-Objects), I’ve been able to create a stanza, but our custom stanzas gets trickier by the time and I don’t quite get it.

Comment: This is the continuation from the post:
Here I leave you with one custom stanza that I have created, and I don’t know if I am doing it right. This I have create with what I have understood from your help. I apologize in advance if it seems a total mess: https://friendpaste.com/3C3JbrHvNfHDdRUZ38aMZG
Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that the timezone difference is an issue. I've modified your example with comments on what I changed and why: https://friendpaste.com/5OGWZfDN96mjkqrhzAOnLK  In short, the main issues were just a conflict in interface resolution, and the syntax of the stanza registration call.